# Displaying Telugu on Terminal or iterm2 applications of Mac OS

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, fonts, terminal

Terminal and iterm2 applications on my Mac don't display Telugu characters properly. The characters get all jumbled up. I see the same issue with other languages like Kannada and Sanskrit. Some characters seem fine but some others are getting jumbled (as if one character is being super-imposed on another).

I set my text-encoding of Terminal to utf-8, did export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 as suggested by other answers but nothing seems to work. Here is my locale:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Enabling "double width" setting did not solve the problem either. I also checked "set locale environment variable on startup". That did not work either.

Note that the characters are being displayed properly in other applications like browsers, word processors, etc. So the problem is local to terminal apps like Terminal and iterm2.

[This is how the word "Telugu" is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElFsu.png)